# How to do Diagonal subtraction of result and current value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a product table and I want to do a zigzag subtraction with price column

I have tried with below query but it does not work for me

```
SELECT price
,price - (SELECT COALESCE(lag(price) OVER (ORDER BY ProductID),price)  AS PayableInQuarter  
FROM @Products WHERE ProductID=1) from @Products
```

Code to create table

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE (ProductID INT, ProductName VARCHAR(20), Price int)

INSERT INTO @Products VALUES (1, 'A', 1000)
INSERT INTO @Products VALUES (2, 'B', 5000)
INSERT INTO @Products VALUES (3, 'C', 9000)
INSERT INTO @Products VALUES (4, 'E', 12000)

SELECT * FROM @Products
```

Expected output as below

```
| ProductId | ProductName | Price | Difference |
|-----------|-------------|-------|------------|
|         1 |           A |  1000 |       1000 |
|         2 |           B |  5000 |       4000 |
|         3 |           C |  9000 |       5000 |
|         4 |           E | 12000 |       7000 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try taking a sort of rolling difference, using the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductID) rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
    FROM @Products
)

SELECT
    ProductID,
    ProductName,
    Price,
    (CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE -1.0 END) *
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (t2.cnt - t2.rn) % 2 = 0
                     THEN t2.Price ELSE -1.0*t2.Price END)
     FROM cte t2
     WHERE t2.ProductID <= t1.ProductID) AS Difference
FROM cte t1
ORDER BY
    ProductID;
```

### Demo